# add header to array

Tags: javascript

I am not sure how to assign them to this header and export them in csv.
Can you please help? Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by export? Do you want to set the result to a string? Have the user download the file? Or write to a new file using `node.js`?

Comment: I want to format them with the header and export them as csv file. I already have a button to do that. Thanks

Comment: click the button -> download the csv file on client side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to split your row data and re-join it with commas to be a proper CSV.

**Note:** The snippet will not allow the CSV to be downloaded, but this should work on any web server.

```js
const encodeCsv = matrix =>
  `data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,${matrix.map(row =>
    row.join(',')).join('\n')}`;

const downloadCsv = (data, headers, filename) => {
  const
    encodedUri = encodeURI(encodeCsv([headers, ...data])),
    link = document.createElement('a');
  link.setAttribute('href', encodedUri);
  link.setAttribute('download', filename);
  document.body.appendChild(link);

  link.click();
};

const
  data = ["1 0 1 02/25/2021", "10 0 1 02/25/2021", "100 0 1 03/04/2021", "11 0 1 02/25/2021", "12 0 1 07/16/2021", "122 0 1 07/19/2021", "1232 0 1 08/11/2021", "1234 0 1 08/11/2021", "1346 0 1 07/16/2021", "143 0 1 07/23/2021"],
  headers = ['number', 'id', 'percent', 'date'];

downloadCsv(data.map(line => line.trim().split(/\s+/)), headers, 'data.csv');
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code.

```
function exportCsv() {
    const array = [
        "1 0 1 02/25/2021", 
        "10 0 1 02/25/2021", 
        "100 0 1 03/04/2021", 
        "11 0 1 02/25/2021", 
        "12 0 1 07/16/2021", 
        "122 0 1 07/19/2021", 
        "1232 0 1 08/11/2021", 
        "1234 0 1 08/11/2021", 
        "1346 0 1 07/16/2021", 
        "143 0 1 07/23/2021"
    ];
    const rows = ["number", "id", "percent", "date"];
    let content = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8," + rows.join(",") + "\n";
    content += array.map(val => val.split(" ")).map(val => val.join(",")).join("\n");
    var encodedUri = encodeURI(content);
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.setAttribute("href", encodedUri);
    link.setAttribute("download", "test.csv");
    link.click();
}
```